what is the suggested maximum torque for machine screwed fasteners directly into wood
What would be the appropriate torque for directly screwing a machine bolt into a threaded wood hole? Or, if this it too variable, perhaps it could be figured as a percentage of the observed torque that would strip such a screw in a specific species of wood.
If the answer is that it should be tested for each situation, what % of the torque that strips would be appropriate?

What's the torque measurement for 'just snug'? ;-) More seriously, this is the kind of thing where I think drivers are specifically contra-indicated. If there's any argument to be made for those who have limited grip strength, perhaps using big bolts going into particularly hard/dense wood, first lubricate, then there are at least two easy solutions for providing added manual rotational force — add or lengthen the lever, use a brace.


What would be the appropriate torque for directly screwing a machine bolt into a threaded wood hole?

My determination is that it should be the rightly famous just snug.
In other contexts instructions such as "screw in until just tight", "tighten until the first resistance is felt" and "turn until snug" are all used, and they pretty much describe the same thing. So there is a lot of precedent for something like this.
Plus, as I think I lay out convincingly below, there's no alternative anyway......

Or, if this it too variable

It is, see below.

If the answer is that it should be tested for each situation, what % of the torque that strips would be appropriate?

I don't believe this is actually a good way to go, but regardless, say it's what you or A. N. Other want to do....
The answer is the ever-frustrating, it depends.
The softness of the wood will be the primary variable here, just mentally comparing threads in cardboard versus metal tells us that.
But in wood, brittleness or crumbliness are also factors. Some woods are hard and strong, but prone to small-scale chipping or crumbling — the very reason that some species, e.g. certain rosewoods and box, were historically preferred for threading over others.
It's also worth noting that wood is by no means anisotropic or amorphous. Often this doesn't matter, but here it could since different locations on a single board may be quite markedly different in terms of how well they thread and then how much hold they can provide if the grain is variable — any amount of rising/falling grain at one location means the wood there acts in a semi-end-grain way (like with mitres).
So no one number is possible for any species.
Strengthening the wood with glue is obviously always there as an option to help level the playing field so to speak, but you'd then have to determine how much strength it adds for each of a number of situations.
I think it's fair to say that A, nobody is going to do the work to determine those numbers in the first place and it is anyway B, unworkable.
Given this, I think it goes without saying that just relying on good old hand feel is the way to go.

The answer is what I suspected.  Beyond that, this means do NOT use such a fastening to pull a board snug if one end does not lay flat. Perhaps a clamp (or weight) could be applied , the board screwed in place, then the clamp/weight released.

Starting with tapping wood for a machine screw does allow for later use of a metal insert should it fail.  The hole size for a metal insert is greater than the outer diameter of the machine screw being applied.
